# Can one Animal Crossing New Horizons digital copy be used on two Switches with two islands

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Can one Animal Crossing New Horizons digital copy be used on two Switches with two islands?

I have two switches. I am happy to configure one as primary and the other as secondary under the same Nintendo Account.

I have one copy of Animal Crossing: New Horizons, which is a digital download. My understanding is it can be [shared across two consoles](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/47524/%7E/how-to-play-your-games-across-multiple-systems).

But when I do so, do I get a separate island on each console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only on the account that purchased it.
A secondary account on the secondary switch cannot play the game at all.
Your purchasing account will be able to download and play the game on the secondary switch, which includes making a new island.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Nintendo account is linked to 1 character and one island at time, this offers you the possibility to play anywhere (1 console in your house and 1 console in your uncle's house as example) and continue the same saved game, not different island. So, according Animal Crossing's ideology: different island = different characters = different account = different purchases.

But what you can do is do a multiplayer session in 1 console (up to 4 players) playing in the same screen.
You can see more information [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYgZmqoqrnY)